# RegOpenKeyEx access denied reading HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: c++, permissions, uac, visual-c++-2010

In Windows 7 (32 bit), I consistently get error 5 (access denied) when I call ::RegOpenKeyEx on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE if I am not running in Administrator mode.

This is my code:

```
result = ::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\MyCompany\\MyApp"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &keySoftware)
```

I am trying to build an app that can be installed for an entire machine as opposed to a specific user. Therefore my installer (which does run in Administrator mode) writes to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, and the installer works fine.

I'd like my app to be able to read the data that my installer has put into the registry. I don't want to change any of the registry data. I have also tried using KEY_READ and KEY_EXECUTE instead of KEY_QUERY_VALUE. But it seems that no matter what I do, I cannot read from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE without using an elevated status. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Your installer needs to adjust the security permissions on your Registry key so that non-admin users are allowed to access it.  Have a look at [`RegSetKeySecurity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379314.aspx), or your installer's equivalent, or any number of command-line tools that are available.  You can create a DACL that enables read-only access for the `Everyone` user group, or for specific user accounts.

**Update**: since you are using Inno Setup, try this in your Registry setup:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\MyCompany\MyApp"; Permissions: everyone-read
```

Or:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\MyCompany\MyApp"; Permissions: users-read
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try some of that, but I'm not certain about the acronym DACL.  I'm using Inno Setup for my installer; so far it has proven to be excellent.

Comment: Read the [Inno documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection), it tells you how to grant permissions on Registry keys.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - That worked like a champ. I'm new to Inno Setup; that detail in the documentation about permissions is a real gem.

Answer (score -1):

Your code as I was writing this answer:

```
result = ::RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\MyCompany\\MyApp"), 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &keySoftware)
```

<del>`RegOpenKeyEx` doesn't support general paths, just direct key names.</del>

<del>To use it you would have to iterate your way down the hierarchy.</del>

`SHRegOpenUSKey` is one alternative <del>that does support general paths</del>:

```
HUSKEY keySoftware;
LSTATUS const result = ::SHRegOpenUSKey(
    L"Software\\Microsoft\\MediaPlayer", KEY_QUERY_VALUE, 0, &keySoftware, TRUE
    );
```

Comment: SHRegOpenUSKey is another API I am not familiar with, but also will look up. I had been iterating, but then started getting the "Access Denied" code, so I started trying some alternatives.

Comment: -1 Your claim that `RegOpenKeyEx()` does not support paths is wrong. `RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\MyCompany\\MyApp"), ...)` works fine, as evident by the fact that it does open the key when the app is run in an elevated state, and gives access denied when not elevated. So clearly `RegOpenKeyEx()` does know how to handle the path just fine. I use paths with `RegCreateKeyEx()` and `RegOpenKeyEx()` all the time, they work fine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You're right. Thanks! I was misled by "The name of the registry subkey to be opened" (saying "name", not "path") in the documentation.